# TAPESTREA: Exciting tools, anyone using this software?

Tags: software

TAPESTREA : Techniques And Paradigms for Expressive Synthesis, Transformation, 
and Rendering of Environmental Audio

I found this software a year or so back, and have a little bit of success with it.

Has anyone been using this that has work they can share? I'd like to find other video examples of people using this software, it looks like it can create / generate  some interesting sound scenes.

Comment: I'm dowloading it now. It looks fun!

Comment: Download - http://taps.cs.princeton.edu/release/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the only videos that I have found. Good introduction of what it can do. vimeo.com/1823416

Answer (score 1):

Oh no, someone has found my secret weapon! Eh, just kidding. I've had it for a while, and have managed to coax some neat stuff out of it, but my results and process of using it are still mostly guesswork and random tinkering. The UI is very well, "research lab". It also seems to be fairly buggy in OS X. I can crash it easier than I can do something cool with it. Still, the technology and concept is definitely neat and worth checking out. Someone with more brainpower than me can probably get a lot more out of it. :)

Comment: @theodorejordan I agree, on OS X it can be a buggy program. It's still a totally cool idea, I hope they continue work on it. 